# Using Keras how and what do I need to export to use my classifier independently?

Tags: python, classification, keras, multilabel-classification, nlp

I have a basic question that I can't seem to find an answer to.

I built and trained with good results (above 90% accuracy) a NLP Log classifier that takes in a UTF-8 payload and classifies it into 32 distinct categories but I am having a hard time writing a simple script that loads all the necessary info from my training and testing session (model.h5 and ?).

### This is the structure of my code.

```
# load data logs and split it 80-20 for training and testing
vocab_size = 500
tokenizer = text.Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)
tokenize.fit_to_text(trainRawLogs)
x_train = tokenize.text_to_matrix(trainRawLogs)
x_test = tokenize.text_to_matrix(testRawLogs)

encoder = labelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(trainRawLogs)

#Model build is simple ReLu - Softmax

model.compile..

model.fit..

model.evaluate..
```

### Now here is my question.

Out of all of this process what do I need to save to build a lightweight classifier? The model? The model and the labels? Anything else? I tried loading the model

Answer (score 1):

In keras you have the option to save the entire model state including the optimizer parameters or simply the model weights. In the first case all you need to do is:

```
model.save(model_path)  
model = load_model(model_path)
```

In the second case you have to first create your model and then load the weights:

```
model.save_weights(model_weight_path)
```

In case model is not already specified:

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add()  
...  

model.load_weights(model_weight_path)
```

https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model